# is it safe to upgrade redis from version 6.0.3/6/9 to 6.2.10?

Tags: redis

I am managing over one hundred instances of redis at version 6.0.3/6/9, since the security issues, manage decision has been made to upgrade all instances to the latest version, but I am not sure if this is safe at all. I looked at the official document but no clue.

From the following page, it says "Upgrading between minor versions does not introduce any application-level compatibility issues.

Minor releases may include new commands and data types that introduce operations-related incompatibilities, including changes in data persistence format and replication protocol."

what does "operations-related incompatibilities" mean? is there any document about what operation maybe impacted? can anybody help? thanks in advance

https://redis.io/docs/about/releases/#minor-versions

look through the official website, but no clue